# Cannot reach Postgres Flexible Server from Web App

Tags: django, postgresql, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a Django app to deploy with a pipeline in azure DevOps  and deploy To Azure cloud resources.
The Django database is a Postgres Flexible Server in the same resource group.
Also I have a virtual network resource in the Group.
The pipeline install dependencies and then exec the tests from a command in a Makefile.
[image: Pipeline step]

[image: Makefile]

In the tests step the Django app cannot reach the Database server, the name doesn't resolve to an IP, I try with the server Ip and get the same error.

[image: Django error]

I didn't set any firewall rule neither private endpoints

Comment: Have you run the same commands on your local machine to deploy your app? If not, please try it. If the deployment locally is successful, the issue may be related to Azure pipeline. Set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and deploy again. If it failed locally, check further on your app and scripts.

Comment: Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, Locally runs because the database server is local too, the issue is because the Azure database is private, so, the pipeline agent is in my machine and cannot reach the database in  Azure. Thank you a lot

Comment: Do you mean it works locally when your DB server is on your local machine? And now, your DB is on Azure Service? Would you please let me know are you using a MS-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent? If it's a self-hosted agent, is it a VM or something else? What does "Azure database is private" means? In your ticket, you said that you had a virtual network resource in the Group. At the same time, you said you didn't set any firewall rule neither private endpoints. What's the virtual network used for?

Comment: I am usin a self hosted agent in my computer with wsl, there I developed with a PG server on my machine too, when try to deploy with the pipeline, the database flexible server changed for the instance in Azure, it was created private with the private dns zone too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to Deploy PostgreSQL with Azure Web App Refer this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=django,windows):-

You can create Azure Web App and PostgreSQL Flexible server separately and deploy your Web app or Create Web App + Database and deploy your web app there.

**For Web App + Database [The Postgresql DB is created with VNET integration connected to Azure Web app]**

[image]

After selecting Web App + Database in Engine select PostgreSQL:-

[image]

*Azure Web app with Vnet integration with PostgreSQL:-*

[image]

[image]

**My Azure Repository with .env file:-**

[image]

I have added the DB **SECRET_KEY** in my **Application Settings** like below  and **AZURE_POSTGRESQL_CONNECTIONSTRING** connection string is created automatically with Web App + Database option:-

[image]

Then I went to Azure Web app > Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Kudu > SSH > And then run the below command to execute the migration like below:-

```py
python manage.py migrate
```

[image]

*I have used below Azure DevOps yaml script:-*

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureServiceConnectionId: 'xxxxx-b9c0-f610xxxx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'siliconpypostgesqlq'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'siliconpypostgesqlq'

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  # Python version: 3.7
  pythonVersion: '3.10'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : siliconpypostgesqlq'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**My Web app loaded successfully like below:-**

[image]

*With Azure Web app and PostgreSQL deployed separately without any Vnet Integration with PostgreSQL access to Public network with Allow Azure Services:-*

[image]

**My PostgreSQL setting:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, The thing is that the pool agent host cannot reach the database because is private, so i need to update my pipeline.